# ExternalName pointing to service in other namespace doesn't resolve unless given full FQDN

Tags: kubernetes, dns, cname, kubernetes-service, coredns

I've a Service `my-service` of type ClusterIP in namespace `A` which can load balance to a few pods. I want to create another Service of type ExternalName in namespace `B` that points to `my-service` in namespace `A`.

I create the following YAML:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: B
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: my-service.A
```

and if I exec into a pod running in namespace `B` and do:

```
# ping my-service
ping: my-service: Name or service not known
```

But if I change the `externalName` in the above YAML to below:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: B
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: my-service.A.svc.cluster.local   <--- full FQDN here
```

things work as expected. Also, if I ping `my-service` directly from a pod in namespace `B` it is being resolved:

```
# ping my-service.A
PING my-service.A.svc.cluster.local (10.0.80.133) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Why `my-service.A` is not resolved to `my-service.A.svc.cluster.local`  in ExternalName Service?

My K8s version is `1.14.8` and uses CoreDNS.

Answer (score 5):

Based on [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) and [okd](https://docs.okd.io/latest/dev_guide/integrating_external_services.html) that's how it's supposed to work

> Kubernetes DNS schedules a DNS Pod and Service on the cluster, and configures the kubelets to tell individual containers to use the DNS Service’s IP to resolve DNS names.
>
> What things get DNS names?
>
> Every Service defined in the cluster (including the DNS server itself) is assigned a DNS name. By default, a client Pod’s DNS search list will include the Pod’s **own namespace and the cluster’s default domain**.

---

> Services are assigned a DNS A or AAAA record, depending on the IP family of the service, for a name of the form **my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example**. This resolves to the cluster IP of the Service.

---

There are logs from kubedns when you want to use my-service.A

```
I0306 09:44:32.424126       1 logs.go:41] skydns: incomplete CNAME chain from "my-service.dis.": rcode 3 is not equal to success
```

That's why you need whole path for the service, which in your situation is

```
my-service.A.svc.cluster.local
```

**Because**

> Using an external domain name service tells the system that the DNS name in the externalName field (example.domain.name in the previous [example](https://docs.okd.io/latest/dev_guide/integrating_external_services.html#mysql-define-service-using-fqdn)) is the location of the resource that backs the service. When a DNS request is made against the Kubernetes DNS server, it returns the externalName in a CNAME record telling the client to look up the returned name to get the IP address.

---

I hope this answer your question. Let me know if you have any more questions.